# how i can create an overlay layout for quick launch?

Tags: android

i want change my **overlayedButton** (**always on top**) to **overlayedLayout** and in this layout put instlled app icon for lunch.
i do not want a widget layout. i want a layout like widget that every where is showing and always on top
 [this image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NP0s.png)

## my HUD class

```
public class HUD extends Service implements OnTouchListener,  View.OnClickListener {

private View topLeftView;

private Button overlayedButton,overlayedButton2;
private float offsetX;
private float offsetY;
private int originalXPos;
private int originalYPos;
private boolean moving;
private WindowManager wm;
private String TAG = "GET_APP";
private LayoutInflater li;
private ViewGroup myview;
private int deviceWidth;
  @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    overlayedButton = new Button(this);
    overlayedButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main);
    overlayedButton.setOnTouchListener(this);
    overlayedButton.setAlpha(0.0f);
    overlayedButton.setBottom(100);
    overlayedButton.setOnClickListener(this);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 0;
    wm.addView(overlayedButton, params);

    topLeftView = new View(this);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams topLeftParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    topLeftParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    topLeftParams.x = 0;
    topLeftParams.y = 0;
    topLeftParams.width = 0;
    topLeftParams.height = 0;
    wm.addView(topLeftView, topLeftParams);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (overlayedButton != null) {
        wm.removeView(overlayedButton);
        wm.removeView(topLeftView);
        overlayedButton = null;
        topLeftView = null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        float x = event.getRawX();
        float y = event.getRawY();

        moving = false;

        int[] location = new int[2];
        overlayedButton.getLocationOnScreen(location);

        originalXPos = location[0];
        originalYPos = location[1];

        offsetX = originalXPos - x;
        offsetY = originalYPos - y;

    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        int[] topLeftLocationOnScreen = new int[2];
        topLeftView.getLocationOnScreen(topLeftLocationOnScreen);

        System.out.println("topLeftY="+topLeftLocationOnScreen[1]);
        System.out.println("originalY="+originalYPos);

        float x = event.getRawX();
        float y = event.getRawY();

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) overlayedButton.getLayoutParams();

        int newX = (int) (offsetX + x);
        int newY = (int) (offsetY + y);

        if (Math.abs(newX - originalXPos) < 1 && Math.abs(newY - originalYPos) < 1 && !moving) {
            return false;
        }

        params.x = newX - (topLeftLocationOnScreen[0]);
        params.y = newY - (topLeftLocationOnScreen[1]);

        wm.updateViewLayout(overlayedButton, params);
        moving = true;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (moving) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Overlay button click event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, ArcMenuActivity.class);
    dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(dialogIntent);
}

}
```

## ArcMenuActivity

```
public class ArcMenuActivity extends Activity {
private int state = 0;
public static final String FAVORITES = "Product_Favorite";
private ArrayList<Intent> Ar;
private Drawable icon;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    state = 1;
    switch (state){
        case 1:{
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_ray);
            final RayMenu rayMenu = (RayMenu) findViewById(R.id.ray_menu);
            Ar = getFavorites(getApplicationContext());
            final int itemCount = Ar.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
                ImageView item = new ImageView(this);
                try {
                    icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(Ar.get(i).getPackage());
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                item.setImageDrawable(icon);
                final int position = i;
                rayMenu.addItem(item, new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Toast.makeText(ArcMenuActivity.this, "position:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(Ar.get(position));
                        finish();
                    }
                });

            }

            break;}
        case 2:{
            break;}
        case 3:{
            break;}
    }

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent svc = new Intent(this, HUD.class);
    startService(svc);


}

public ArrayList<Intent> getFavorites(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    List<Intent> favorites;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences("INTENT",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)) {
        String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(FAVORITES, null);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Intent[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites,
                Intent[].class);

        favorites = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
        favorites = new ArrayList<Intent>(favorites);
    } else
        return null;

    return (ArrayList<Intent>) favorites;
}

private void initArcMenu(ArcMenu menu, int[] itemDrawables) {
    final int itemCount = itemDrawables.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        ImageView item = new ImageView(this);
        item.setImageResource(itemDrawables[i]);

        final int position = i;
        menu.addItem(item, new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(ArcMenuActivity.this, "position:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: nobody knows what your `overlayedLayout` is

Comment: it's look like muti window app [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bank.multi.window)